# Printing from a progressive web app

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app that uses the following javscript code:

```
 prnWnd = window.open();
 prnWnd.document.title = "Printing...";
 $('<p style="font-size: 20px">Please wait while the content is rendered...</p>').appendTo(prnWnd.document.body);
```

Normally, this opens a new browser window with a text inside. Works perfect on a browser, but when I add the manifest and service worker related code to launch the page as a progressive web app, this no longer work. It simply opens a new window, empty. Any ideas?

Comment: did you able to find solution on this problem?

Comment: @zer09 still stuck on this